# Vuejs3/Nodejs - single project structure

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, vuejs3

I am trying to create a new project based on Vuejs3 and Nodejs.
I need following:

- Admin app (vuetify) which will be sort of CMS - Vue
- Public app (haven't decided on template yet) - Vue
- Backend API - Node

Basically, I want these 3 projects to be merged into a single project so that I have only one code repository.

This is desired folder structure:

```
client
  - admin
  - public
common
  - ...
server
  - ...
.env
package.json
README.md
```

I did some research and found that with webpack I can override default `src` folder location but in my case I have two frontend apps which I want to combine into a single project.

Any suggestions?

Comment: admin and public are fully vue-cli apps?

Comment: @BallonUra correct